# Dataframe with Nested Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, nested

I have a dataframe with another nested dataframe. Here is a minimal example:

```
data <- data.frame(var1 = 1:5)
data$var2 = data.frame(w = 1:5, y = 6:10)
```

```
View(data)
var1 var2.w var2.y
1    1      1      6
2    2      2      7
3    3      3      8
4    4      4      9
5    5      5     10
```

How do I convert the data to one dataframe where I can get all vectors directly via `data$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is reapply the `data.frame` with `do.call`

```
data <- do.call(data.frame, data)
str(data)
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ var1  : int  1 2 3 4 5
# $ var2.w: int  1 2 3 4 5
# $ var2.y: int  6 7 8 9 10
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(var1 = 1:5)
data$var2 = data.frame(w = 1:5, y = 6:10)
```